# How can I start Activities and TabActivities inside an ActivityGroup?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have a problem in this code:

```
getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id, intent);
```

Inside a class extends `ActivityGroup`, starts a activity but I need start a `TabActivity` and this doesn't work.

How can I start `Activities` and `TabActivities` inside an `ActivityGroup`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `startChildActivity(id,intent);`

And the startChildActivity() method defined,must be in the class which extends **ActivityGroup**..

```
public class TabGroupActivity extends ActivityGroup {

    private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        if (mIdList == null) mIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    /**
     * This is called when a child activity of this one calls its finish method. 
     * This implementation calls {@link LocalActivityManager#destroyActivity} on the child activity
     * and starts the previous activity.
     * If the last child activity just called finish(),this activity (the parent),
     * calls finish to finish the entire group.
     */
  @Override
  public void finishFromChild(Activity child) {
      LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
      int index = mIdList.size()-1;

      if (index < 1) {
          finish();
          return;
      }

      manager.destroyActivity(mIdList.get(index), true);
      mIdList.remove(index); index--;
      String lastId = mIdList.get(index);
      Intent lastIntent = manager.getActivity(lastId).getIntent();
      Window newWindow = manager.startActivity(lastId, lastIntent);
      setContentView(newWindow.getDecorView());
  }

  /**
   * Starts an Activity as a child Activity to this.
   * @param Id Unique identifier of the activity to be started.
   * @param intent The Intent describing the activity to be started.
   * @throws android.content.ActivityNotFoundException.
   */
  public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));

      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }

  /*public void startChildActivityForResult(String Id, Intent intent,int key) {     
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivityForResult(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),key);
      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }    
  }*/

  /**
   * The primary purpose is to prevent systems before android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
   * from calling their default KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK during onKeyDown.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  /**
   * Overrides the default implementation for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK 
   * so that all systems call onBackPressed().
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
          onBackPressed();
          return true;
      }
      return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
  }

  /**
   * If a Child Activity handles KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
   * Simply override and add this method.
   */
  @Override
  public void  onBackPressed  () {
      int length = mIdList.size();
      if ( length > 1) {
          Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
          current.finish();
      }
  }
}
```

For more info. see here

http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html